# Does Closure exist in a Nested function without variables

Tags: javascript, closures

Can we say a closure exist in this code

```
function foo(){
        return function foo2(){
                   console.log("Inner Function");
          }
}

let x = foo();
x();
```

Answer (score 1):

No the inner function is not a closure here. It is not accessing any variable which is outside the scope.

Here is the snapshot from chrome console.

[image: Inner function]

But when the inner function access a variable defined outside its scope the whole environment that is function with references to its surrounding becomes a closure. You can see scope closure in the console

[image: Closure]

Comment: That's wrong closure is created regardless of the variables